# VariableDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

Getting a very strange error when trying to access my blog or `/admin` page.

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /admin/
```

**Error during template rendering:**

```
In template /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/grappelli_safe/templates/admin/base.html, error at line 19
```

**This is the line:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="
      {% static "mezzanine/js/"|add:settings.JQUERY_FILENAME %}
      "></script>
```

I have no clue what so ever how to solve this strange error. Any ideas what's causing this and how to solve it? When removing the line, the error persists.

Edit:

**Full error:**

```
Failed lookup for key [settings] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, `'True': True}, {}, {}, {'site_header': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10300f650>, 'site_title': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10300f610>, 'title': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10300f690>, 'has_permission': True, 'app_list': [{'app_url': u'/admin/auth/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/auth/group/', 'object_name': 'Group', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7b50>, 'add_url': u'/admin/auth/group/add/'}, {'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/auth/user/', 'object_name': 'User', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e73d0>, 'add_url': u'/admin/auth/user/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x103019310>, 'app_label': 'auth'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/blog/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/blog/blogcategory/', 'object_name': 'BlogCategory', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7610>, 'add_url': u'/admin/blog/blogcategory/add/'}, {'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/blog/blogpost/', 'object_name': 'BlogPost', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7050>, 'add_url': u'/admin/blog/blogpost/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'Blog', 'app_label': u'blog'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/conf/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/conf/setting/', 'object_name': 'Setting', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7790>, 'add_url': u'/admin/conf/setting/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'Conf', 'app_label': u'conf'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/forms/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/forms/form/', 'object_name': 'Form', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7950>, 'add_url': u'/admin/forms/form/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'Forms', 'app_label': u'forms'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/galleries/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/galleries/gallery/', 'object_name': 'Gallery', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7290>, 'add_url': u'/admin/galleries/gallery/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'Galleries', 'app_label': u'galleries'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/generic/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': False, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/generic/threadedcomment/', 'object_name': 'ThreadedComment', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e76d0>}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'Generic', 'app_label': u'generic'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/pages/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/pages/link/', 'object_name': 'Link', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e70d0>, 'add_url': u'/admin/pages/link/add/'}, {'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/pages/page/', 'object_name': 'Page', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7190>, 'add_url': u'/admin/pages/page/add/'}, {'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/pages/richtextpage/', 'object_name': 'RichTextPage', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e75d0>, 'add_url': u'/admin/pages/richtextpage/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'Pages', 'app_label': u'pages'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/redirects/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/redirects/redirect/', 'object_name': 'Redirect', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e71d0>, 'add_url': u'/admin/redirects/redirect/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x103019910>, 'app_label': 'redirects'}, {'app_url': u'/admin/sites/', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True}, 'admin_url': u'/admin/sites/site/', 'object_name': 'Site', 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1049e7690>, 'add_url': u'/admin/sites/site/add/'}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x103019ed0>, 'app_label': 'sites'}], 'site_url': '/'}]"`
```

**Set up a view now but I get the error:**

```
Failed lookup for key [jquery_filename] in u"[{'False': False,'None': None, 'True': True}, {u'params': {}}, {}, {}]"
```

**My views.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request, template='templates/base.html'):
    context = {'jquery_filename': settings.JQUERY_FILENAME}
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

**base.html:**

```
<script src="{% static "mezzanine/js/"|add:jquery_filename %}"></script>
```

Comment: Please show the *full* error, not just random lines from it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Edited now with the full error output.

Comment: do you have `JQUERY_FILENAME` specified in your settings file?

Comment: @iulian: No I have not.

Comment: And did you put `settings` into your context?

Comment: What do you mean by that? @KlausD.

Comment: You have to render a template with a context to make variables accessible inside the template. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/ ! If it is a base template all renderings importing it need the variable in the context.